# Lightest option for MySQL proxy

Tags: mysql, proxy

I'm looking for the most lightweight program that is capable of serving as a MySQL proxy to a remote server, unifying all connections to the proxy into a single connection to the remote MySQL server (so only the proxy will be on my machine).

I installed mysql-router but then, per [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-deploying-basic-routing.html) from the docs, it seems it requires the normal MySQL server package, which I want to avoid completely (unless it's just needed for essential binaries).

What's the best & most lightweight proxy that meets my requirements, and install procedure?

For Ubuntu 20.04.

**EDIT**: Nevermind, `mysql-router` doesn't require MySQL server to be installed in the same machine, I understood the document wrong. However, after setting a proper sample setup it seems not to allow me to do what I want, and that led me to realize I might need to clarify what's what I want:

1. Multiple applications connect to the router/proxy against the same MySQL credentials (same DB and user)
2. Router/proxy establishes a single connection using the same MySQL credentials than the client applications; that is, **doesn't simply forward each connection coming from each application to the server.**
3. Queries from all clients will end in the single **MySQL** connection from the proxy to the remote server, and get response back to each requesting client, accordingly

For context, my motivation is that `max_user_connections` at the remote server is not enough for all my clients, and I don't have the required privileges...

Comment: Not really understand why you need a mysql proxy, can't you just open an SSH tunnel and then connect to this?

Comment: @pLumo Hadn't thought about that, but that would add some slowness by nature and I don't have access to the remote machine other than for MySQL, so AFAIK can't do a SSH tunnel.